# window.addEventListener code is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, menu

Please i have issue in my JS code i built this code because i'd like when the visitor click on another div (not the menu )the menu will close if it open 
this is the code but this code don't work on mobile phones but it work in developer tools on chrome or firefox

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
    var box = document.getElementById('narvbar_menu');
    if (event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box){
        box.style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("close_menu").style.display="none";
    }
});
</script>
```

Best regards

Comment: did you try using the 'click' event instead of 'mouseup'?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events

Answer (score 1):

This is because `"mouseup"` doesn't fire on mobile devices. Just also listen for `"touchend"`:

**EDIT:** The below code should append event listeners for both `"mouseup"` and `"touchend"` to window.

```
<script>
    ["mouseup", "touchend"].forEach(function(e) {
        window.addEventListener(e, function(event){
            var box = document.getElementById('narvbar_menu');
            if (event.target != box && event.target.parentNode != box){
                box.style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("close_menu").style.display="none";
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

If you don't want to listen for multiple events, `"click"` should work for both mobile and desktop:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(event) { ... }
```

Comment: Just a nit-pick, in native JS, with [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) argument, you can attach only a single event type.

Comment: I have edited my solution, it should work now with thanks to @Teemu for pointing out that an event listener can only accept one event at a time.